# Why am I getting segmentation fault for this?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am getting "RE (SIGSEGV)" for the following line of code:

```
int dp[105][100005];
```

My laptop has 8GB of RAM. Is it not sufficient to store 10^7 integers?

Comment: The stack size allocated to each process is limited by default, usually to a few megabytes, so 10^7 integers is very likely to overflow it.  We have a question somewhere about large local arrays causing stack overflow, but I can't find it right now.  The short answer is that you ought to allocate it dynamically instead, which should give you access to all the machine's memory (subject to various limitations).

Comment: In every question, please always include a tag for the programming language you are using.  I'm guessing [tag:c] from the syntax, but please update the tags if not.

Answer (score 0):

It is if you dynamically allocate, as in:

```c
int* dp = calloc(105 * 100005, sizeof(int));
```

Where you can use that 1D array in a 2D fashion via offset calculations.

You cannot fit something this big on the stack, it's just too huge. The stack is limited in size.